# If statement trigger functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two functions: FunctionPart1 and FunctionPart2. Both are triggers onSubmit. Both are triggers other functions:

FunctionPart1 trigger: Function1, Function2, Function3.

FunctionPart2 trigger: Function4, Function5, Function6.

I have two forms which trigger both functions (FunctionPart1 & 2) but I need trigger only one. It can't change from trigger menu so I wonder if can be add some if statement which it would allow blocking unnecessary triggering of both functions.
I came up with the following, but of course it does not work.

Maybe you have some ideas?

```
Function All(){  //--> trigger onSubmit

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

//we check if the A2 in different sheet is not empty, then it trigger Functions:
if(ss.getSheetByName('Response1').getRange('A2').getValue() != ""){ 

Function1()
Function2()
FUnction3() 
}

else if(ss.getSheetByName('Response2').getRange('A2').getValue() != ""){

Function4()
Function5()
Function6()
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah there is only one trigger for the spreadsheet. But you can use the range parameter in the event object to figure out which response sheet it applies to. Range.getSheet().

Comment: I don't think it speed up script because I would have to add this condition to every function

Comment: It would be better to have just one function and use the range to figure out which form issued the trigger and then call those two extra functions from that one function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Check the Value for null and not for "".

ss.getSheetByName('Response1').getRange('A2').getValue() != null